# How to show only the attributes from a API json response that matches records in my models DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rest

**Issue:** I am unable to have my API show me the results I want that match my StoreProduct model record stored in the database.

What I want: To display orders that have specific product_id's in them.

**I have the following API json response**

```
[[#<ShopifyAPI::LineItem:0x000055ef6161f110 @attributes={"id"=>1959792476209, "variant_id"=>15345627234353, "title"=>"Burton Custom Freestlye 151 37", "quantity"=>1, "sku"=>"", "variant_title"=>nil, "vendor"=>"Burton", "fulfillment_service"=>"manual", "product_id"=>19600013786737, ...
```

At the last record, you will see "product_id".  I have this in in my StoreProduct model as store_product_id.  I want to only display the product_id if it matches one i have in my StoreProduct database.

For instance, if I had this information stored in my own model/db, I would do:

```
@store_products = StoreProduct.all
@store_orders = Orders.where(product_id: @store_products.each {|store_product| store_product.store_product_id})
```

**I tried this in my view:**

```
<% @store_orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <% order.line_items.each do |line| %>
          <% if line.product_id == @store_products.each {|store_product| store_product.store_product_id} %>
            <td><%= line.product_id %></td>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
@store_products = StoreProduct.all
@store_orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.all
```

And nothing appears.(I am doing this on the front-end before i migrate this to the controller so i can see what is happening)

If i remove the if statement, all of product_id's appear from the orders.

When i tried using a `.where`, it gives me an error that I am unable to use "where" with the Shopify API.

**Question:** How can I make it so only orders and product ID's appear that match any of the store_product.store_product_id's I have in the StoreProduct DB?

Comment: `if line.product_id == @store_products.each {|store_product| store_product.store_product_id}`

Comment: ^ This is not correct use of `each`. Remember `each` returns the array it's called on. What would here here in your case is to replace `each` with `find` ([doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html)). You can also use a method like `select` to filter down the list. I recommend reading up on Ruby's [enumerable methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html)

Comment: Sorry I thought you were 2 dif people lol

Comment: I tried replacing it with "find" and "select" but still no results appear.  When i specifically use `if line.product_id == "1234567890"` it works but not with the looping?.  I really want if ANY product_id from the API and store_product_id from my Model match, to then result.

Comment: I recommend going in with a debugger such as pry and messing around with your variables. I'm afraid I don't have an exact solution for you here.